# Making Greyscale image in Silverstripe

Tags: php, image, gd, silverstripe

I'd like to be able to return an image in Black&white in a controller, so I can use it in a template. On [this page](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/image) I found that the GD class has a greyscale method. Unfortunately I don't understand the GD class and how I can use it. I tried doing

```
$final = $image->getFormattedImage('greyscale',36,36,36);
```

But that didn't work. It does return an image object with a new URL but the image does not exist.

Can anyone explain to me how to make an imageobject into a greyscale image in a Silverstripe page Controller?

Comment: have a look here:
http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/rotating-and-greyscaling-images-using-gd-and-decorators/

Comment: Yes, I've found that unfortunately, this article applies to 2.4, and a lot has changed since 2.4. So it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I had a go myself and this is what I came up with:

**_config.php**

```
Object::add_extension('Image', 'Greyscaled');
```

**UPDATE:** as of SilverStripe 3.1, you should use the config system instead of `_config.php`. Put the following in your `mysite/_config/config.yml` (Don't forget to `?flush=1` to reload the config cache after adding it):

```
Image:
  extensions:
    - 'Greyscaled'
```

---

**Greyscaled.php**

```php
<?php
class Greyscaled extends DataExtension {
    //This allows the template to pick up "GreyscaleImage" property, it requests a copy of the image from the cache or if it doesn't exist, generates a new one
    public function GreyscaleImage($RGB = '76 147 29') {
        return $this->owner->getFormattedImage('GreyscaleImage', $RGB);
    }

    //This is called internally by "generateFormattedImage" when the item is not already cached
    public function generateGreyscaleImage(GD $gd, $RGB) {
        $Vars = explode(' ', $RGB);
        return $gd->greyscale($Vars[0], $Vars[1], $Vars[2]);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2:** With newer Versions of 3.1 ?? you can pass in more than 2 parameters and GD has been renamed to Image_Backend. This way you do not have spaces between the RGB-values in the image-name. Be aware $gd->greyscale needs a lot of juice - so you probable better downsize first and GreyscaleImage afterwards.

**UPDATE3:** Since this answer got some votes recently I assume people still using it, but I think in 2017 CSS filters are in many cases a better choice. Prefixed you'll have close to 90% coverage.
[css-filters on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

```php
<?php
class Greyscaled extends DataExtension {
    public function GreyscaleImage($R = '76', $G = '147', $B = '29') {
        return $this->owner->getFormattedImage('GreyscaleImage', $R, $G, $B);
    }
    public function generateGreyscaleImage(Image_Backend $gd, $R, $G, $B) {
        return $gd->greyscale($R, $G, $B);
    }
}
```

and in the template:

```php
<img src="$Images.GreyscaleImage.CroppedImage(1000,400).URL" alt="$Images.Title" />
```

[Silverstripe 3.1 Image API](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-Image.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for this. Sorry but it's not on packagist just yet.
https://github.com/NightJar/ssrigging-greyscaleimages

Comment: True but the module cannot set RGB values and also does not use sane default weight for channels. The output does not look as it should :(